# Opinion on a webapp ide using java ee

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee, project

I want to create an web application written in java using java ee, tomcat, ajax and some additional frameworks. The app is an IDE for C/C++, login with usernames from the linux system, and have access to their /home folder. And through java access 'gcc/g++', and receive the output back to the screen.

I'm asking for an opinion on what technologies to use, or even if is this possible. Or, if you know an existing application like this, please tell.

Thank you

Comment: This question is simply too broad. There's no way to tell from this question what specific advice you're asking for. Vote to close.

Comment: You want to write a web application that is an IDE and that launches c++ code? Why?

Answer (score 0):

The security aspects of this seem daunting.  You are basically trying to create a development environment within a browser?  I have always used ant/msbuild/makefiles to do my building and utilize the IDE just for a sanity check.  Seems like alot of work for something your could provide by letting users SSH into a development machine and open their IDE from there.  Us developers can get a little protective of their toolsets.  You could provide the same thing by enabling XDMCP and allowing remote logins.  However, if this is a project to see if you can do it, then there are alot of interesting problems hidden to solve.